# Magento 2.3 REST API not working for default store - rest/V1/inventory/source-items

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, rest-api

In Magento2.3

I'm using http://localhost/new-jk/rest/V1/inventory/source-items

it is working fine for all stores but only default is not updating properly

The service is updating quantity of product but the salable quantity does not change only for default stock.

can someone face this issue? please guide

Comment: By seeing you query it looks like default might be removed from stores list somehow, Can you please check store listing API and check all available stores.

Answer (score 1):

> By seeing you query it looks like default might be removed from stores
>   list somehow, Can you please check store listing API and check all
>   available stores

```
 <host>/rest/<store_code>/V1/inventory/source-items
```

But if you haven't configure any stores then pass default

```
 <host>/rest/all/V1/inventory/source-items
```

For `all` store you need to pass `website_id` in post parameters

**And to fetch all store data using API**

> storeStoreRepositoryV1

---

**Group repository interface**

```
http://magento.host/index.php/rest/V1/store/storeGroups
```

- `method : GET`
- `Authorization : Bearer <admin token>`

This will return `website_id`, `root_category_id`, `default_store_id`, `name`, `code`

---

Answer (score 0):

You can simply indicate to your endpoint that you are fetching data from default store.
It should look like below:

```
http://localhost/new-jk/rest/default/V1/inventory/source-items
```

Comment: i am executing this with curl functions and using passing this array in json format $body = json_encode(['sourceItems' =>[
                    ['source_code' => $stock['source'], 'sku' => $data['sku'], 'quantity'=>$data['stock'], 'status'=> $product_status]
                ]]);

Comment: it is working fine for other store but the salable quantity in default stock not updating

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to update the product inventory for the default stock.

Step 1: https://domain.com/rest/V1/inventory/source-items

Use Method : **Post**

Step 2: Send parameters in the api body:

`{ "sourceItems": [{ "sku": "testseller", "source_code": "default", "quantity": 200, "status": 1 }] }`

Step 3: Send the admin token in the API header.

Using this you will update the inventory for each stock.